# Integral ${\large\int}_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(x-a\ln2\cdot\tan x\right)}{\left(e^{2\pi a\tan x}-1\right)\cdot\cos x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, trigonometry

Analyzing results *Mathematica* returned for several integrals and series, and putting pieces together, I came up with this conjecture:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(x-a\ln2\cdot\tan x\right)}{\left(e^{2\pi a\tan x}-1\right)\cdot\cos x}\,dx\stackrel{\color{gray}?}=\frac{\operatorname{li}\left(2^a\right)}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{2\,a-1+a\cdot\Re\,{_2F_1}(1,1;a;2)}{4\,a\,(1-a)}\color{gray}{,\,a>0\land a\ne1 }$$
Can we prove this result? It is possible to generalize it to complex values of the parameter $a$?

Comment: i don't know if it helps but the substitution $y=\tan(x)$ brings the integral in a much nicer form...

Comment: So
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(cy)}{(e^{2 \pi a y}-1)(1+y^2)}dy
$$

Comment: sorry, one of my comments somehow disappeared. If i'm not mistaken, your integral is equivalent to the above minus the same integral differentiated w.r.t. to $c$. Then set $c=a \log(2)$ in the end...

Comment: For $a>0 \land a\neq 1$ we have $$\Re\,{_2F_1}(1,1;a;2)=(1-a)\cdot\Re\Phi(2,1,a-1).$$

Comment: Hello, based on my above hints, one can derive a solution by applying Abel Plana formula. I don't have the time today, but i think i can give some details tomorrow. But if everyone else wants to try, go ahead. It will work, i'm quiet sure

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function essentially the result follows from one of the integral representations there...

Comment: @user153012 How do we get this formula?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov I have found this experimentally, earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only managed to arrive at a closed form for the integral in a different form from that which was proposed in the question.

---

**Preliminary Manipulations:**

\begin{align}
\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sin(x-a\ln{2}\tan{x})}{(e^{2\pi a\tan{x}}-1)\cos{x}}\ {\rm d}x
&=\Im\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{-i(a\ln{2})x}}{(e^{2\pi ax}-1)(1-ix)}\ {\rm d}x\tag1\\
&=\Im\int^0_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-i(a\ln{2})x}}{1-ix}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{2\pi ax}-1}\right)\ {\rm d}x\tag2\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}\Im\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{i(a\ln{2})x}}{1+ix}\ {\rm d}x}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\Im\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-i(a\ln{2})x}}{(e^{2\pi ax}-1)(1-ix)}\ {\rm d}x}\tag3
\end{align}

---

Explanation: 
$(1)$: Substituted $x\mapsto\arctan{x}$ 
$(2)$: Substituted $x\mapsto-x$. 
$(3)$: Averaged $(1)$ and $(2)$.

---

**Contour Integration: The First Integral**

Integrating $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{1+iz}$ along the contour $[0,R]\cup Re^{i[0,\pi/2]}\cup i[R,0]$,
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\Im\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{i(a\ln{2})x}}{1+ix}\ {\rm d}x}
&=\Im\left(\color{grey}{\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}f(z)}+\frac{i}{2}PV\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{-(a\ln{2})y}}{1-y}\ {\rm d}y\right)\\
&=\left.-\frac{1}{2}e^{-a\ln{2}}\operatorname{Ei}(a\ln{2}(1-y))\right|^\infty_{y=0}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(a\ln{2})}{e^{a\ln{2}}}\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{\operatorname{li}(2^a)}{2^{a+1}}}
\end{align}

---

**Contour Integration: The Second Integral**

$\text{Case}\ 1$: $a\in\mathbb{R}^+\backslash\mathbb{Z}^+$

Integrate $\displaystyle g(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{-i(a\ln{2})z}}{(e^{2\pi az}-1)(1-iz)}$ along the contour $[-R,R]\cup Re^{i[2\pi,\pi]}$. This (clockwise) contour encloses only simple poles at $z=-i$ and $z=-\frac{in}{a}$. Summing up the residues,
\begin{align}
\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\Im\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-i(a\ln{2})x}}{(e^{2\pi ax}-1)(1-ix)}\ {\rm d}x}
&=\color{red}{-}\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}g(z)+2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-i}g(z)+2\pi i\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-in/a}g(z)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi a}+2\pi i\cdot\frac{i}{2^a}\frac{1}{e^{-2\pi ia}-1}+2\pi i\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}\pi(a-n)}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4a}+\frac{\pi\cot(\pi a)}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^n(n-a)}\\
&\color{red}{=\frac{1}{4a}+\frac{\pi\cot(\pi a)}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2},1,-a\right)}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the lerch transcendent defined as $\displaystyle\Phi(z,s,\alpha)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{(n+\alpha)^s}$ for $|z|<1$ and $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Z}^-$. (It is implemented in Mathematica or Wolfram as $\text{HurwitzLerchPhi[z,s,a]}$, not $\text{LerchPhi[z,s,a]}$).

$\text{Case}\ 2$: $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

In this case, the pole at $z=-i$ is order $2$. Applying the residue theorem once again,
\begin{align}
\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\Im\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-i(a\ln{2})x}}{(e^{2\pi ax}-1)(1-ix)}\ {\rm d}x}
&=-\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi a}+2\pi i\cdot\frac{\ln{2}-\pi i}{2^{a+1}\pi}+2\pi i\sum^\infty_{\substack{n=1\\n\neq a}}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}\pi(a-n)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4a}-\frac{\ln{2}}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{\substack{n=0\\n\neq a}}\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-a)}\\
&=\frac{1}{4a}\color{grey}{-\frac{\ln{2}}{2^{a+1}}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{a-1}_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-a)}+\color{grey}{\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=a+1-(a+1)}\frac{1}{2^{n+(a+1)}(n+(a+1)-a)}}\\
&\color{red}{=\frac{1}{4a}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{a-1}_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-a)}}
\end{align}

---

**The Final Result:**

Combining both blue and red integrals gives
\begin{align}
\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sin(x-a\ln{2}\tan{x})}{(e^{2\pi a\tan{x}}-1)\cos{x}}\ {\rm d}x
=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\small{\frac{\mathrm{li}(2^a)}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{4a}+\frac{\pi\cot(\pi a)}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2},1,-a\right)}, &\text{if } a\in\mathbb{R}^+\backslash\mathbb{Z}^+\\
\displaystyle\small{\frac{\mathrm{li}(2^a)}{2^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{4a}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{a-1}_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^{n}(n-a)}}, &\text{if } a\in\mathbb{Z}^+
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice @M.N.C.E ! I was doing almost the same calculation, arriving at ur case one, but after i didn't got the expected answer (given in the question) for the other i case i thought what i do is wrong so i never brought it to an end ... (+1)